# Saving output of MMQGIS Geocoder to British National Grid receive error message "Latitude or longitude exceeded limits"

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, mmqgis

I have used MMQGIS geocoder multiple times and then saved the output with a CRS of British National Grid (BNG) 27700 with no issue. However, I am currently trying to achieve the same result but get the following error message:

`Export to vector file failed.
Error: Failed to transform a point while drawing a feature with ID '48'. Writing stopped. (Exception: forward transform of
(-2.026525, 0.783758)
PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits)`

The error states that the latitude or longitude exceeded limits.

When I open up the attribute table for the MMQGIS output I cannot see any obvious problem. There is no x or y fields but that is normal for MMQGIS because it does not create them.

The project CRS is set to BNG 27700 and the output from MMQGIS is ESPG:4326, WGS 84.

[image: MMQGIS projection]

Comment: Maybe you should set the project CRS to EPSG:27700 as well while you are running the geocoder.

Comment: Please copy the text of the error message as a code block instead of adding a screen capture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have points that are not in the UK.

These will be outside the extents of the projection system and cannot be converted to EPSG:27700.

Zoom to the layer extent and delete all points not in the UK.

Comment: It is true that the point is not inside the valid area of EPSG:27700 but there may be something else that makes the real issue. This succeeds `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:27700
-2.026525 0.783758
397132.247562689 -5440970.51883177 246.321689824574`

Comment: You were right, there was one point way out of the BNG extent. However when I have gone it to it and deleted it I still get the same error message. I then zoom to layer and it appears to be remembering the deleted poibt even though it is not there?

Comment: Did you save your edits (turn off digitising)?